# Get multiple optional properties with multiple optional qualifiers on Wikidata Query Service

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I want to load the following data of specific humans with the Wikidata Query Service:

**properties**

- birth date
- lifestyles

**qualifiers**

- start times of the lifestyles
- end times of the lifestyles

And I want exactly one row for each human in the output, no matter if no properties/qualifiers or multiple properties/qualifiers are set.

I managed to create a query which works with humans who have at least one lifestyle, but when there's none, the query takes a long time and instead of empty cells many lifestyles, start and end times are loaded which are not related to the human.

This is the query for the humans *Q185140*, *Q463434* and *Q3378937* and *Q3378937* doesn't have a lifestyle, but still the *lifestyles*, *lifestylesStarts* and *lifestylesEnds* cells aren't empty as expected and instead full of values:

```
SELECT ?human ?humanLabel 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lifestyleLabel;separator="|") AS ?lifestyles) 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lifestyleStart;separator="|") AS ?lifestylesStarts) 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lifestyleEnd;separator="|") AS ?lifestylesEnds) 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dateBirth;separator="|") AS ?dateBirths) 
WHERE { 
    VALUES ?human { wd:Q185140 wd:Q463434 wd:Q3378937 } . 
    OPTIONAL{ ?human p:P1576 ?statement . }
    OPTIONAL{ ?statement ps:P1576 ?lifestyle . } 
    OPTIONAL{ ?statement pq:P580 ?lifestyleStart . } 
    OPTIONAL{ ?statement pq:P582 ?lifestyleEnd . } 
    OPTIONAL{ ?human wdt:P569 ?dateBirth . } 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { 
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" . 
        ?human rdfs:label ?humanLabel . 
        ?lifestyle rdfs:label ?lifestyleLabel . 
    }
}
GROUP BY ?human ?humanLabel
```

You can run the query and see the output [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fhuman%20%3FhumanLabel%20%0A%09%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FlifestyleLabel%3Bseparator%3D%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3Flifestyles%29%20%0A%09%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FlifestyleStart%3Bseparator%3D%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3FlifestylesStarts%29%20%0A%09%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FlifestyleEnd%3Bseparator%3D%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3FlifestylesEnds%29%20%0A%09%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%20%3FdateBirth%3Bseparator%3D%22%7C%22%29%20AS%20%3FdateBirths%29%20%0A%09WHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%3Fhuman%20%7B%20wd%3AQ185140%20wd%3AQ463434%20wd%3AQ3378937%20%7D%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fhuman%20p%3AP1576%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP1576%20%3Flifestyle%20.%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP580%20%3FlifestyleStart%20.%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FlifestyleEnd%20.%20%7D%20%0A%09%09OPTIONAL%7B%20%3Fhuman%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FdateBirth%20.%20%7D%20%0A%09%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20%0A%09%09%09bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20.%20%0A%09%09%09%3Fhuman%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FhumanLabel%20.%20%0A%09%09%09%3Flifestyle%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FlifestyleLabel%20.%20%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09GROUP%20BY%20%3Fhuman%20%3FhumanLabel).

What do I have to change to get empty cells if properties/qualifiers are not set?

Comment: https://w.wiki/HDp? 1. use nested `optional`s 2. don't start with `optional`.  3. do you really need `group_concat`?

Comment: @StanislavKralin regarding point 3 -> *"And I want exactly one row for each human in the output, no matter if no properties/qualifiers or multiple properties/qualifiers are set."* - so if a human has multiple lifestyles, I assume yes. BUT: the main issue is, that with multiple lifestyles everything would be mixed up, i.e. you wouldn't have the relation between which lifestyle started and ended when, because as you know - order doesn't work in `group_concat` - so in the current example, it's impossible to know for "Marianne Thieme" the relation between "vegetarianism|veganism" and the dates

Comment: here we go (https://w.wiki/HE7) :`SELECT ?human ?humanLabel 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?lifestyle;separator="|") AS ?lifestyles) 
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dateBirth;separator="|") AS ?dateBirths) 
WHERE { 
VALUES ?human { wd:Q185140 wd:Q463434 wd:Q3378937 } . 
?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5 .
`

Comment: `OPTIONAL{ ?human p:P1576 ?statement . 
?statement ps:P1576/rdfs:label ?lifestyleLabel filter (lang(?lifestyleLabel) = 'en')  
OPTIONAL{ ?statement pq:P580 ?lifestyleStart } 
OPTIONAL{ ?statement pq:P582 ?lifestyleEnd } 
BIND(IF(BOUND(?lifestyleEnd), CONCAT(" -- ", str(?lifestyleEnd)), "") as ?lsEndText)
BIND(CONCAT(str(?lifestyleLabel), " (", str(?lifestyleStart), ?lsEndText, ")") as ?lifestyle)
}OPTIONAL{ ?human wdt:P569 ?dateBirth . } 
SERVICE wikibase:label { 
bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" . 
?human rdfs:label ?humanLabel . 
}}GROUP BY ?human ?humanLabel`

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks for helping me out with the misplaced curly bracket. Regarding 2.: Why shouldn't I start with an `optional`? The thing is, in the end I also want to list non-human instances so every value can be variable.

Comment: @UninformedUser You're right regarding Stanislav's 3. point. Your code fixes the issue you mentioned like a charm, thanks a lot for this!

Comment: As for `optional`, see Q1b in https://blog.blazegraph.com/?p=928